# rolled theorem question

Tags: calculus

sketch a function y=f(x) such that f(3)=5 and f(1)=5 but f'(x)never =0 . explain why it does not contradict Rolle's theorem

Comment: A big part of maths is being creative.  Try it!  Start sketching a function where $f(3)=5$ and $f(1)=5$.  As a hint, maybe you might want your function to not be continuous.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples especially when your functions are not continuous.  Here is a continuous example:

f(x)=6-|x-2|

Rolle's theorem requires differentiability while my function is not differentiable at x=2!